# Can't refresh my div [asp.net mvc 5]

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to refresh my div after an update, but it doesn't work. I have a View which calls Partial View with a content field (#FullName,....).

After the update I want to refresh this field, but it doesn't work.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditParticipantALL(Shared.Participant participant)
{
    GetParticipantModel model = new GetParticipantModel();
    model.FillDDL();
    model.Participants = participant;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.EditParticipantAll();
    }

    return PartialView("_ParticipantDetail", model);
}
```

Script jquery in the main view:

```
jQuery('#AllSubmit').click(function () {

    var model = new Object()

    model.ParticipantCode = @Model.Participants.ParticipantCode;
    model.FullName = jQuery('#Fullname').val();  
    model.Country = jQuery('#Country').val();
    model.CountryHQ = jQuery('#CountryHQ').val();
    model.InstitutionalSector = jQuery('#InstitutionalSector').val();
    model.Shortname = jQuery('#Shortname').val();
    model.FiscalNumber = jQuery('#FiscalNumber').val();
    model.StateDate = jQuery('#StateDate').val();
    model.Branch = jQuery('#Branch').val();
    model.SpecialCondition = jQuery('#SpecialCondition').val();
    model.DelayNotification = jQuery('#DelayNotification').val();
    model.StateCDR = jQuery('#StateCDR').val();
    model.StartDate = jQuery('#StartDate').val();
    model.EndDate = jQuery('#EndDate').val();
    model.FinancialGroup = jQuery('#FinancialGroup').val();
    model.Insurance = jQuery('#Insurance').val();
    model.Active = jQuery('#Active').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EditParticipantALL","GetParticipant")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { participant:model },
        success: function (data) {   flipCard_1(jQuery('.fsc-comp-flipcard-1'), 0);
            jQuery('#datacard').html(data) }    
    })   
})
```

Partial View :

```
<div id="datacard">
    <label class="fsc-label-2">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Participants.Fullname)
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What isn't working? What message are you receiving?

Comment: It needs to just `data: model,` but it appears your generating a javascript object based on controls generated from the model, in which, all you need is `data: $('form').serialize(),`

Comment: i don't have a form and i mut work with this method

Comment: i haven't error message but my page is not refresh

Comment: does it calls your action?

Comment: yes my action work i have problem with the refresh only

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove `dataType: "json"` because `dataType` is telling jQuery what kind of response to expect and your response is an Html. and if you set datatype to json jQuery will execute error function instead of success method:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EditParticipantALL","GetParticipant")',
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: "json",
        data: { participant:model },
        success: function (data) {   flipCard_1(jQuery('.fsc-comp-flipcard-1'), 0);
            jQuery('#datacard').html(data) }    
    })
```